# packages.xml is restored after reboot

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-services

This is my first question here. I hope developers will help me out.

I have XOLO A500 device on which Google Play services is not being installed because of "Using the same shared id" problem. To resolve the problem, I had rooted my phone and taken access of system through ADB. Following procedure I had made.

1) Rooted the phone and installed ADB to access the android system.
2) chmod 666 to packages.xml inside /data/system.
3) Pulled the packages.xml using command adb pull /data/system/packages.xml
4) Edited the packages.xml and removed the sharedUserId attribute for the particular app.
5) Pushed back packages.xml
6) Removed the dalvik cache.
7) Reboot.

All I am doing as su.

The problem here is after reboot, the packages.xml file is again restored as the original one. Please help me regarding this.

Edit 1: I am using ICS

Edit 2: Here is how I have done everything.

1. Started USB debugging.
2. Connected the phone and started ADB.
3. adb pull /data/system/packages.xml
4. Edited packages.xml and saved the file
5. adb shell
6. su
7. chmod 666 /data/system/packages.xml
8. exit
9. exit
10. adb push packages.xml /data/system
11. adb shell
12. su
13. chmod 664 /data/system/packages.xml
14. rm /data/dalvik-cache/*
15. exit
16. exit
17. adb reboot

Thanks and Regards

Comment: Did you re-appply permissions when pushing it back into the system?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have tried that as well but nothing worked. I have edited the question so that you can see how I have done everything and if possible, please help me.

Comment: chmod 666 means that all users can read and write but cannot execute

Comment: should i try that with chmod 777

Comment: You can, but check out this [understanding chmod](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm). This might shed some better light on the situation.

Comment: Tried that as well but the file is again restored.

Comment: Have you changed permissions for the directory as well?

Comment: no. I have not tried for that. Let me check that as well by providing 777 to both directory and file.

Comment: You'll need to change permission to chmod 644 before restarting. That will keep it from restoring itself. Sorry for the delay, rebuilding a transmission as I remembered the right chmod.

Comment: Let me know and I'll  post as answer

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have tried that also but it seems to be not working.

Comment: As a surprise, permissions also restored.

Comment: Then there's something else wrong with your system. 644 should have fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I will post again if I find anything working.

Comment: 10 - 4 , I  would like to know what the problem is too

Answer (score 1):

`sharedUserId` is simply a copy of the parameter of the same name from the [Android Manifest file](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#uid). When you clear the dalvik cache and reboot, the `sharedUserId` attribute is read from the original apk files and `packages.xml` is rewritten. You'll probably need to disassemble the apk, edit the manifest, and reassemble the apk using a tool like [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/). Note that the new apk you create will not be signed, so it will not be automatically updated though the Play Store.

Comment: Who reads the sharedUserId attribute from the original apk? PackageManager? `packages.xml` is rewritten - who updates or rewrites it?  Also who creates package.xml file and when?